# How to specify a specific English font for Tesseract v5 OCR?

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

### Problem

I am using Tesseract v5 and IronOCR to perform OCR on files written in the [IBM Plex Mono](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/IBM+Plex+Mono) font. It is having issues recognizing dotted zeroes because it is confusing them with `6`, `8`, and `9`.

How can I train Tesseract OCR to recognize a dotted zero, or specify that the font is specifically IBM Plex Mono?

Here is a sample image. It is currently parsed as follows, with incorrectly parsed values highlighted in bold:

### Input

[image: Source Image]

### Output

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.3 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 1.8 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 3.8 | 0.3 | **06.06** |
| 1.1 | 1.2 | 0.0 |
| **06.9** | 0.8 | 0.0 |
| 3.0 | 3.1 | **06.0** |
| 1.7 | 0.6 | 0.0 |

### Source Code

I am using IronOCR with Tesseract to parse. Here is my configuration for the parser:

```
Input.AddPdf("myfile.pdf");
Input.Deskew();  // fixes rotation and perspective
Input.DeNoise(); // fixes digital noise and poor scanning
Ocr.Configuration.BlackListCharacters = "X@©®¢*%,";
Ocr.Language = OcrLanguage.EnglishBest;
```